# Find all $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrices $A$ such that $2A^3 = B$

Tags: matrices, geometry

I need to find all possible $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices $A$ such that
$$
2A^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\sqrt{3}\\
\sqrt{3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I have thought of the given matrix, divided by $2$, as the $\sin$-$\cos$ rotation matrix with angle $\pi/3$. And hence if we take the rotation matrix with angle $7\pi/9$ and cube it we should get A. So for my answer I have got that all possible orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrices as the rotation matrix with angle $7\pi/9 + 2n\pi$, $n$ an integer.

I feel like I am missing out on something simple and my answer is wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry i am new to this and unsure how to correctly input a matrix, the first bracket in the top line is the first row of 2x2 matrix and and the second bracket is the second row

Comment: Welcome!  If you right-click on the math stuff and choose Show Math as -> TeX commands, you can see how I obtained the output above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, in that if you divide both sides of the initial equation by $2$ you have

$A^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha)\\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}$

where $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$, and $n$ is an integer.

As you might be aware, for any $2\times 2$ sin-cos rotation matrix $A$ that rotates by angle $\theta + (2n\pi)$, the matrix $A^k$ (for integer $k$) is another sin-cos rotation matrix that rotates by $k(\theta + 2n\pi)$.

Thus, for $k=3$, we have

$\large 3\theta=\alpha=\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$

$\large \theta=\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{2n\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got $7\pi/9$: we need the angle $\theta$ for $A$ to satisfy $3\theta=\pi/3+2n\pi$ for $n$ an integer, meaning
$$
\theta = \frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{2n\pi}{3}.
$$
But besides that, your thinking is right on target.